# website not displaying right on godady hosting

Tags: jquery, html

i have a website here is a jsbin

http://jsbin.com/eqodep/1/

although jquery is not working there the menu are supposed to be really cool they expand and animate really cool
now here my website

www.albuquerqueautomotiveservice.com

but i just published this website about 15 mins ago
and on firefox it looks bad, the menu its not even showing

and on ie it shows perfectly but jquery doesnt work the menu effects dont work
and also the images with links dont work..

did i messup on the doc type or something

sorry this is my first website and i need help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the files are not all there.

> - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>     http://www.albuquerqueautomotiveservice.com/images/logo.jpg
> - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>     http://www.albuquerqueautomotiveservice.com/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js
> - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>     http://www.albuquerqueautomotiveservice.com/js/jquerymenu.js

Comment: do you think i need to wait for them  or something??